# What will this command do

Tags: linux, shell, vim

I accidentally  ran the following command in my console.It was a copy paste error.

```
vim  -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/25-xyz-https.conf.
```

But after that my **25-xyz-https.conf** got corrupted. Eventhough I recovered the file just curious to understand what has happened.

Comment: @jww I disagree with that. See my comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45342439/what-will-this-command-do/45342497#comment77647050_45342497

Comment: @hek2mgl  - You seem to be pleading the argument, *"I'm a programmer so my questions are on-topic"*. First and foremost, the question has to be about programming and development. Its codified in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) *"[the site's goal] ... build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming"*. How or why copy and paste failed in someone's favorite text editor certainly does not meet the criteria. Out of curiosity, would you also consider questions about Word copy/paste problems to be on-topic? Many Windows programmers use Word, not Vim.

Comment: I just quoted the [help/on-topic](http://stackoverflow/help/on-topic) page. Is the shell a tool commonly used by programmers? *Yes*. Is vim a tool commonly used by programmers? *Yes*. So what's wrong here? PS: Yes, you'll find a lot of *notepad++* questions on stackoverflow. *word* seems not that widely used since there are not so many questions. ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl - *"So what's wrong here?"* - That's easy. Its not a question related to programming or development. I find it disingenuous to claim a failed copy and paste in a terminal is "shell programming", or some programmers use Vim so all Vim questions are on-topic.

Comment: I recommend to bring this up on meta if you have still concerns. Please notify me. I'm curious what the community will say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens:

```
vim -
```

means open stdin in `vim`.

```
> file
```

is an [output redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) by the shell. Stdout of the (vim) process will get stored in `file`. `file` will get truncated by the shell *before* the (vim) process get's started.

---

I recommend to always put a `#` into the shell before pasting things into the shell. That gives you a chance to review the line before executing it, especially if you paste the line together with the line break at the end. (which would execute it right away)

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance... What does this question and answer have to do with programming and development?

Comment: Sure, it is not something like `[java] How to avoid NullPointerException here...` but for shell programming it is important to know how the shell will interprete a command line.

Comment: Besides that the [help/on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help) page says that questions about *software tools commonly used by programmers* are on topic. The shell and vim are imo tools commonly used by programmers.

Answer (score 4):

The shell ran "vim -" and then redirected the output from that command to /etc/apache2/sites-available/25-xyz-htttps.conf

If you run "vim -" you'll see it do something like this:

```
Vim: reading from stdin...
```

You will have to hit ^C to break out of reading from stdin, then :q to exit vim.

This is because many utilities interpret the '-' character as stdin (or stdout, depending on the context).

If you did something like:

```
date | vim -
```

This would open 'vim' with the contents of the document showing the current date.  There is no open file, you could not simply `:w` to save the file, but you could `:w./thedate.txt` to save the contents to `./thedate.txt`.  The important thing is that the output of the 'date' command became the input to the 'vim' command.

After that, the `>` character just redirects stdout from the whole "vim -" session to overwrite the file provided.